# reshaping data into cross tabulation

Tags: r

I need to transform this dataset :

```
   user year type
1     1 2012    A
2     2 2012    C
3     3 2012    C
4     4 2012    B
5     5 2012    C
6     6 2012    A
7     7 2012    A
8     8 2012    A
9     9 2012    C
10   10 2012    C
11    1 2013    B
12    2 2013    C
13    3 2013    C
14    4 2013    C
15    5 2013    C
16    6 2013    A
17    7 2013    C
18    8 2013    A
19    9 2013    B
20   10 2013    C
```

with dput

```
DF <-structure(list(user = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), 
year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2012", 
"2013"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("user", 
"year", "type"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to ave a cross tabulation this way

```
    A(2012) B(2012) C(2012)
A(2013) a   b   c
B(2013) d   e   f
C(2013) g   h   i
```

where a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h are frequencies ( h : count of users with type C in 2013 and type B in 2012)

I tried with dcast, melt, xtabs but I don't achieve it.

Any idea?

thx

Edit: the solution need to work with unordered dataframe, and with missing row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Is the Solution I found. 
I thinks thats is the most effective:

```
library(reshape2)    
with(dcast(DF,user~year),table(`2012`,`2013`))
```

Comment: Similar to this approach is `table(reshape(DF, direction = "wide", idvar = "user", timevar = "year")[-1])`

Answer (score 3):

Yet another similar idea:

```
do.call(table, split(DF$type, DF$year))
#    2013
#2012 A B C
#   A 2 1 1
#   B 0 0 1
#   C 0 1 4
```

Looks like `table` can handle "list" arguments conveniently, so `table(split(DF$type, DF$year))` works too.

Comment: Thks for this proposition, but the user variable is not respected : see: do.call(table, split(DF[sample(1:dim(DF)[1]),]$type, DF[sample(1:dim(DF)[1]),]$year))

Comment: @Bakalegum : ATM, only something like `table(lapply(split(DF[c("user", "type")], DF$year), function(x) x$type[order(x$user)]))` comes to my mind as a straighforward fix.